# The total revenue from the sale of x stereos is given by $R(x)=3000(1-\frac{x}{600})^2$. Find the marginal average revenue.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

The total revenue from the sale of x stereos is given by $R(x)=3000(1-\frac{x}{600})^2$. Find the marginal average revenue.

$R(x)=3000(1-\frac{x}{600})^2$

A. $0.008-(\frac{3000}{x^2})$

B. $5-(\frac{600}{x^2})$

C. $0.008-(\frac{600}{x^2})$

D. $5-(\frac{3000}{x^2})$

I know that I need to use the marginal revenue formula for this problem which would be MR=dR/dx

But when I find the derivative what I get is $-10+(\frac{x}{60})$

Am I missing something, like is there another formula that I must apply due to it saying AVERAGE. Any advice on how to continue approaching this problem would be appreciated. Should I multiply by another x. I just have no idea how to get to any of those answer choices from the derivative that I have gotten.

Comment: Im not exactly sure I am a little confused. How would I do it that way?

Comment: It seems that you don't know what the "marginal average revenue" is. How should we know?

Answer (score 1):

Good evening,
The average revenue it is known as the revenue obtained per unit sold, and it is calculated dividing the total revenue (*R*) by the units sold (*x*).
So, the AR in this case is: $$AR(x) = \frac{3000}{x} \left(1-\frac{x}{600}\right)^2$$
If we want to obtain the marginal average revenue we only need to calculate the derivative of the preceding equation:$$\frac{dAR(x)}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{3000}{x} \left(1-\frac{x}{600}\right)^2\right) = \frac{1}{120} - \frac{3000}{x^2}$$
Finally, we can conclude that the answer for this problem is A :)